# Double Integration with Integral2 using PRACMA gives error Error in fun(x, y, ...) : argument "c" is missing, with no default

Tags: r, integral

I wonder if you can help please.  I'm trying to take the results of one integration in to the next.  The first integration calculates the value of c as follows:

```
library(pracma)
f <- function(x,y) x^2*y
xmin <- -1; xmax <- 1
ymin <- function(x) x^2; ymax <-1
integral <- integral2(f, xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax)
integral$Q
```

This gives a value of 0.1904762 which is the value of integral without c, but since we need c⋅integral without c = 1 we find c by 1 / integral

```
1 / integral$Q
```

Which is equal to 5.25.  We next incorporate this value of c in to my formula given below (this code fails)

```
 f <- function(x,y,c) c * x^2 * y
 c <- 5.25
 xmin <- 1; xmax <- 0
 ymin <- function(x) x^2; ymax <-function (x) x
 I<- integral2(f, xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax)$Q 
 I$Q
```

Which then results in the error

```
Error in fun(x, y, ...) : argument "c" is missing, with no default.
```

How is the value of c incorporated in to the second integral2 code?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried `integral2(f, xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax, c = c)`? This uses the `...` parameter which can be used, [according to the documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pracma/versions/1.9.9/topics/integral2), parameters passed to function.

Comment: Works like a charm - thanks!